# How can I prevent blank lines from being counted in line numbers in Latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

In the poem I have written in blockquote in Latex, I would like to show the line count. However, I do not want blank lines to count as line numbers. For counting line numbers, I use the lineno.sty package in Latex. If I write \resetlinenumber[5] in the empty line so that the next line (the first line of the second paragraph) is counted as the fifth line, then latex counts the first line of the first paragraph as the fifth line, which is not what I want. Is it possible to avoid counting empty lines in line numbers?

Here is the chunk of compilable code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 0.8in, right = 0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%answer lettering
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\actenum}[1]{
    \expandafter\@actenum\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@actenum}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or (\textbf{A}) \or (\textbf{B}) \or (\textbf{C}) \or (\textbf{D}) \or (\textbf{E}) \else\@ctrerr\fi
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\actenum}{\@actenum}{B}
\makeatother
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#2
 }
\newenvironment{blockquote}{%
  \par%
  \medskip
  \leftskip=4em\rightskip=2em%
  \noindent\ignorespaces}{%
  \par\medskip}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}
\makeatother
\begin{center}
    \begin{fminipage}{6in}
        \begin{blockquote}
            \begin{internallinenumbers}
                \resetlinenumber
                Last night I heard your voice, mother,\\
                The words you sang to me\\
                When I, a little barefoot boy,\\
                Knelt down against your knee.\\
                
                And tears gushed from my heart, mother,\\
                And passed beyond its wall,\\
                But though the fountain reached my throat\\
                The drops refused to fall.\\
                
                'Tis ten years since you died, mother,\\
                Just ten dark years of pain,\\
                And oh, I only wish that I\\
                Could weep just once again.
            \end{internallinenumbers}
        \end{blockquote}
    \end{fminipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [mre]

Comment: I did write a chunk of my code and output.

Comment: Please don't just post a code fragment, but a minimal, but compilable document including the necessary packages etc

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I just edited and posted a minimal compilable latex code. I would appreciate it if you can provide me with some pointers to solve the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the problem by not having empty lines at all:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 0.8in, right = 0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%answer lettering
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\actenum}[1]{
    \expandafter\@actenum\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@actenum}[1]{
    \ifcase#1\or (\textbf{A}) \or (\textbf{B}) \or (\textbf{C}) \or (\textbf{D}) \or (\textbf{E}) \else\@ctrerr\fi
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\actenum}{\@actenum}{B}
\makeatother
\newsavebox{\fminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{fminipage}{m O{\fboxsep}}
 {\par\kern#2\noindent\begin{lrbox}{\fminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \makebox[#1]{%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
    \fbox{\usebox{\fminipagebox}}%
    \kern\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax
  }\par\kern#2
 }
\newenvironment{blockquote}{%
  \par%
  \medskip
  \leftskip=4em\rightskip=2em%
  \noindent\ignorespaces}{%
  \par\medskip}
\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}
\makeatother
\begin{center}
    \begin{fminipage}{6in}
        \begin{blockquote}
            \begin{internallinenumbers}
                \obeylines
                \resetlinenumber
                Last night I heard your voice, mother,
                The words you sang to me
                When I, a little barefoot boy,
                Knelt down against your knee.\medskip
                
                And tears gushed from my heart, mother,
                And passed beyond its wall,
                But though the fountain reached my throat
                The drops refused to fall.\medskip
                
                'Tis ten years since you died, mother,
                Just ten dark years of pain,
                And oh, I only wish that I
                Could weep just once again.
            \end{internallinenumbers}
        \end{blockquote}
    \end{fminipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]